# Difference between R-tree and B+-tree

Tags: b-tree

Does anyone know,what is difference between B+-tree and R-tree?

I am trying to do an assignment related to this question, but not sure about my answer,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

R-Tree supports multidimensional index. For instance, you can use it for geographical coordinates [latitude,longitude] .

Although it is called a tree, but it does not like one, the algorithms used for R-Tree has essential difference. You can read more on it on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree
I also advice you to read this article http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/googles-s2-geometry-on-the-sphere-cells-and-hilbert-curve/ if you are interested in R-Tree applications.

B+ Tree works only with one dimensional value, an integer ID for example.

However, both store the data only in leafs.